# Javascript object change values between lines

Tags: javascript, arrays, global-variables, javascript-objects, console.log

I am creating a Snake game (like those on old phones). I have a snippet of code below, which seems to exhibit the bizarre behavior of an object changing its value between lines.

The function `makeSnakeArray` is called when the game starts, or when the snake touches itself (the game restarts). It returns the new snake which is an array of objects with `x` and `y` properties to be stored in the global variable `snakeArray`.

The first time it is called, everything works fine. However, when it is called to restart the game, the `x` and `y` values are different in `consoleLog1` and `consoleLog2` (see code comment).

In `consoleLog1`, the `x` and `y` values are as what I expected as calculated in the function. However, in `consoleLog2`, the `tempArray` prints out what the `snakeArray` was when it called for the game to restart (and I made sure to clear the `snakeArray` by setting `snakeArray = [];` before calling the `makeSnakeArray` function). As a result, the snake does not start in the middle of the screen like it does the first time, but it just seems to continue around where it left off.

Why does this happen?

Function:

```
function makeSnakeArray(){
  var tempArray = [];

  //Get the position of the head of the snake
  var halfWidth = Math.floor(canvasWidth/2) * blockSize;
  var halfHeight = Math.floor(canvasHeight/2) * blockSize;

  //Add in each block of the snake to the snake array, starting with the head
  for (var i = 0; i < startingSnakeLength; i++){  

    //Create and initialize the snakeBlock
    var snakeBlock = {
      x: halfWidth,
      y: halfHeight + (i*blockSize),
    }

    console.log(snakeBlock); //consoleLog1
    tempArray.push(snakeBlock);
  }

  console.log(tempArray);//consoleLog2
  return tempArray;
}
```

Example output:

`consoleLog1`

```
{x: 180, y: 180}
{x: 180, y: 195}
{x: 180, y: 210}
{x: 180, y: 225}
{x: 180, y: 240}
```

`consoleLog2`

```
0:{x: 60, y: 270}
1:{x: 60, y: 285}
2:{x: 60, y: 300}
3:{x: 60, y: 315}
4:{x: 60, y: 330}
```

Here is the current version of the snake game, if you wanted to see the full code: https://codepen.io/vrsivananda/pen/NvJyGJ?editors=0010

Comment: It seems like the global positions are not properly reset, the snake seems to continue where it was.

Comment: What do you mean, and how do I reset the global positions?

Comment: sorry i mean your global snake array

Comment: When I use `console.log(snakeArray)` after `snakeArray = []`, the console prints out `[]`, so I think it should be properly reset? Is there another way to check? (Also I was wondering how the `snakeArray` is playing a part here, since this is `tempArray`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a debugging of your code with dev tools, and makeSnakeArray() function seem to work well. The issue is with updateSnake() function.

```
//Push this into the front of the snakeArray
  snakeArray.unshift(newHead);

  //If the head is the same place as the apple, then get a new apple and do not pop the tail off the snake
  if(newHead.x == apple.x && newHead.y == apple.y){
    apple = placeRandomApple();
  }
  else{
    //Delete the tail fo the snakeArray
    snakeArray.pop();
  }
  //Redraw the canvas
  drawCanvas();
```

At this part you shouldn't update snake with a new head, if you know that game just was restarted. Plus you shouldn't cut the tail in this case either.

The easiest thing will be just to put a return statement after you know that game got restarted:

```
for (var i = 0; i < snakeArray.length; i++){
    //If it is, restart the game
    if(newHead.x == snakeArray[i].x && newHead.y == snakeArray[i].y){
      restartSnakeGame();
      return;
      console.log("restarting");
    }
  }
```

To avoid all snake body manipulation

Comment: You're right! Thank you very much! I did not realize that after calling `restartSnakeGame()`, it will go back to the `updateSnake()` function and continue with the snake body manipulation. Thanks for all the trouble! :)